# super viewdidload giving me a no visible @interface for uitableview declares for the selector viewdidload

Tags: ios, selector, visible, viewdidload

Here is my current code. I have not even gotten past the `viewDidLoad` method override because on the line where it says `super viewdidload` it throws the error `@interface` for `uitableview` declares for the selector `viewdidload`.

I am not too familiar with iPhone development and i am still beginning. Can someone please help me with this

my code

```
@interface myUITVC : UITableViewController UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;

@end


@implementation myUITVC

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't have to declare the table delegate and data source if you're subclassing UITableViewController (since UITableViewController declares it.)

   Change

   ```
   @interface myUITVC : UITableViewController UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
   ```

   to

   ```
   @interface myUITVC : UITableViewController
   ```
2. You're missing a capital "D" in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the post to have the capital D. I have it correctly typed in my code. It is still throwing a fit. I dont get it :(.

Comment: @0x7fffffff It wouldn't hurt anything, but it's not required since they're declared in the interface for UITableViewController.  I suggested deleting them since they're redundant.

Comment: Do you mean the UITableViewDelegate and UITableviewDataSource is redundant? I omitted both of those.

Comment: I am such a noob. I had it typed as UITableView and not UITableViewController...It's late guys, don't hate.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're just missing a `<` before the `UITableViewDelegate` declaration.